# Creation problem with appropriate struct for URL data in JSON format. Source URL in example

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

Url source code : https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=warsaw&appid=5ca98c08c8abd2bf1fdbd601c3cf3d7e

I tried this code but it's not correct, i have problem with writing appropriate struct.

```
    struct Weather: Codable {

    let weather : [cos]
    let base: String


    }

struct cos : Codable {

    let main: String

}


    let url = URL(string:  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=warsaw&appid=5ca98c08c8abd2bf1fdbd601c3cf3d7e")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        json()
    }


func json() {
         guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, response, error) in


            guard let data = data, error == nil, response != nil
                else {
                    print("zle cos")
                    return                   
            }
            print("downloaded")
            do{
                let downloaded =try JSONDecoder().decode([Weather].self,from: 
                                    data)
                print("ok")
                print(downloaded[0].)
            } catch {
                print("error")
           }
        }.resume()    
    }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling the webservice? Are you using SwiftyJSON or Alamofire? At the minute, with that code, all you're doing is writing out some strings for an endpoint that doesn't exist.

Comment: I gave you explanation below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not represent the entire data, I left some work for you

Please read the JSON carefully, all dictionaries (`{}`) can be decoded into a struct, all values in double quotes are `String`, floating point numeric values are `Double`, the other `Int`, the `Int` dates starting with 1523... can be decoded to `Date` with the appropriate date strategy:

```
let jsonString = """
{"coord":{"lon":21.01,"lat":52.23},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":294.15,"pressure":1012,"humidity":52,"temp_min":294.15,"temp_max":294.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.7,"deg":90},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1523548800,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5374,"message":0.0023,"country":"PL","sunrise":1523504666,"sunset":1523554192},"id":756135,"name":"Warsaw","cod":200}
"""

struct Root : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate
    let weather : [Weather]
    let base : String
    let main : Main
    let dt : Date
}

struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let main, description, icon : String
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double
    let pressure, humidity : Int
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I gave you plus for ths answer.