# JSON decodable swift 4

Tags: json, swift4, decode, xcode9.2

I'm having a terrible time creating a public struct for the following JSON.  I'm trying to extract the temp and humidity.  I've tried to to extract the following JSON but I think I'm having a problem with way I'm identifying each of the variables.

Here's the JSON:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-82.26,"lat":27.76},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":66.24,"pressure":1021,"humidity":63,"temp_min":62.6,"temp_max":69.8},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":8.05,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1523500500,"sys":{"type":1,"id":726,"message":0.0051,"country":"US","sunrise":1523531237,"sunset":1523577156},"id":420006939,"name":"Brandon","cod":200}
```

And here's the struct

```
public struct Page: Decodable {

private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case coord = "coord", weather = "weather", mainz = "main", visibility = "visibility", wind = "wind", clouds = "clouds", dt = "dt", sys = "sys", id = "id", name = "name", cod = "cod"}

let coord: String
let weather: [String]
let mainz: String
let visibility: Int
let wind: String
let clouds: String
let dt: Int
let sys: String
let id: Int
let name: String
let cod: Int


public struct Main: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case temp = "temp", pressure = "pressure",humidity = "humidity", temp_min = "temp_min", temp_max = "temp_max"
    }
    let temp: Int
    let pressure: Int
    let humidity: Int
    let temp_min: Int
    let temp_max: Int
}
```

...and the code I'm using the decode...

```
     //             Make the POST call and handle it in a completion handler
    let task =  session.dataTask(with: components.url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do
        {

            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Page.self, from: data)

            for main in result.mainz {
               print(main.humidity)

            }

        }catch

        {print("Figure it out")

        }



    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801606/how-to-create-struct-for-json-data-in-swift-4/49801912#49801912

Comment: First thing is you need to know how to read JSON. Look at the very first thing in the JSON: `"coord":{"lon":-82.26,"lat":27.76}`. Well, that thing called `"coord"` is not a string; it's a dictionary. But you're typing your `coord` as String. So that will never succeed. — I could go on, but _you_ are the one who needs to go on. Think about the type of each thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create structures to capture whatever you want. For example, if you're interested in the temperatures and the coordinates, create structures for those:

```
struct WeatherTemperature: Codable {
    let temp: Double
    let pressure: Double
    let humidity: Double
    let tempMin: Double
    let tempMax: Double
}

struct WeatherCoordinate: Codable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "lat"
        case longitude = "lon"
    }
}
```

Then create a structure for the whole response:

```
struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let coord: WeatherCoordinate
    let main: WeatherTemperature
}
```

Note, I only create properties for those keys I care about.

And then decode it:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let responseObject = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(responseObject.coord)
    print(responseObject.main)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That resulted in:

> WeatherCoordinate #1(latitude: 27.760000000000002, longitude: -82.260000000000005)
>
> WeatherTemperature #1(temp: 66.239999999999995, pressure: 1021.0, humidity: 63.0, tempMin: 62.600000000000001, tempMax: 69.799999999999997)

Clearly, add whatever other structures/properties you care about, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Note, I'd rather not let the JSON dictate my property names, so, for example, I specified a key decoding strategy for my decoder to convert from JSON snake_case to Swift camelCase.

I also like longer property names, so where I wanted more expressive names (`latitude` and `longitude` rather than `lat` and `lon`), I defined `CodingKeys` for those. But do whatever you want on this score.

Comment: Thank you for this breakdown.  It not only helped me answer the question, but understand the best way to decode JSON in the future.  Thanks again.